# Does weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ imply weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;L^1(\Omega))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Does weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ imply weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;L^1(\Omega))$?

I tried to prove it the following way:

Let $u_n$ converge weakly to $u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2)$, then it holds by definition $\int_0^T (u_n - u, \phi) \longrightarrow 0$ for alle $\phi \in L^2(0,T;L^2) = (L^2(0,T;L^2))'$. And the definition of weak convergence is $L^2(0,T;L^1)$ would be:
$\int_0^T (u_n - u, \phi) \longrightarrow 0$  for all $\phi \in L^2(0,T;L^\infty) = (L^2(0,T;L^1))'$.

And since the space $L^2(0,T;L^\infty)$ is a subset of $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ we can say that weak convergence of a sequence in in $L^2(0,T;L^2(Ω))$ implies weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;L^1(Ω))$.
Is this correct?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you done?

Comment: Let $u_n$ converge weakly to $u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2))$, then it holds by definition $ \int_{0}^{T} (u_n - u, \phi) \longrightarrow 0$ for all $\phi \in L^2(0,T;L^2))$. And the definition of weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;L^1))$ would be: $\int_{0}^{T} (u_n - u, \phi) \longrightarrow 0$ for all $ \phi \in L^2(0,T;L^\infty))$.

Comment: And since the space $L^2(0,T;L^\infty)$ is a subset of $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ we can say that weak convergence of a sequence in in $L^2(0,T;L^2(Ω))$ implies weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;L^1(Ω))$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You only need a subset of the test functions.